# Call a function inside class when unhide a Record in Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Is it possible somehow in Typo3 if a Backend User is unhiding a Record to call a php function inside a class?

In my Case:
FE User is creating a Record hidden. If the Backend User checks this Record and unhide it to show it in frontend I need to send data to the CRM of my client via a class->function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to write an extension (probably you're writing some right now)

You need to use some TCE hooks ie.

```
processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(array &$incomingFieldArray, $table, $id, t3lib_TCEmain &$reference)
```

or

```
processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations($status, $table, $id, $fieldArray, &$reference)
```

Here is [some article](http://www.abcnet.ch/blog/blog-details/article/writing-typo3-backend-hooks-into-your-own-extensions.html) about hooks usage. If you have TemplaVoila installed, you can also check how they are implementing the hooks - `/typo3conf/ext/templavoila/class.tx_templavoila_tcemain.php` and `/typo3conf/ext/templavoila/ext_localconf.php`